# T ( n ) = 4 T ( n/ 3) + lg n

Tags: time-complexity

How do i solve this recurance relation? T(n) = 4T(n/3) + lg n

I know that Master-Theorem-Case 1 applies but i dont understand why. The way i approach this until now is this one.
a=4, b=3, f(n)=lg n.

Is lg n = (lg10 n) or (lg2 n) and i know that because of (lge n) it doesn´t really matter but i still dont understand why it doesn´t matter if it is lg10 or lg2. I could calculate (lg10 n) / (lg2 n) or sth. and for some reason it doesn´t matter but why?... but lets go on.

n^log3^4 ~ 1.26 but what is lg n in terms of n^someting.

Another example so maybe you understand me.
If i had f(n) = square root of n and not lg n it would be f(n) = n^0.5.
So n^1.26 <= n^0.5 for an e > 0. For e = 1, first case,  f(n) becomes element of n^logb^(a-e) = n^log3^(4-1) = n^log3^3. Is n^0.5 element of n^1? Yes? because it is smaller?, so this leads to n^logb^a, or T(N) = O(N^logba) or O(n^log3^4).

If this is correct how do i follow this way for f(n) = lg n?

I hope you understood my question, i cannot format properly all the n^logba stuff.

Comment: This is a site for programming-related questions, so unfortunately math questions are off-topic here, but you might get help over at [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. It perhaps belongs on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

No. The growth rate of logarithmic function is less than any polynomial function with the exponential greater than 0. That is to say even something like x^0.0000001 will eventually grow faster than log x.

So in this case its O(n^log_3 4).